# Quick Limit Question (complex)

Tags: real-analysis, limits, roots

1. The problem statement, all variables and given/known data

Trying to understand this limit:
[image]
where $r>0$
2. Relevant equations

I think it's best to proceed by writing this as:

$ N=1 \pm \frac{\sqrt{Ae^{2rt}}}{\sqrt{1-Ae^{2rt}}} $

3. The attempt at a solution

since $r>0 $ the exponential term $\to $ $\infty$ and then since $A<0$ I get two results for $ lim_{t \to \infty} Ae^{2rt} $ depending on  $ |A| $.

a) If $|A| < 1 $ it goes to zero.
if b) $ |A| \geq 1 $ it goes to $-\infty$

and where the magnitude of A is not specified in the question.

If it was however for case a) the limit is of an determinate form: $1 \pm \frac{0}{1} = 1 $

however for b) i get $ 1 \pm \frac{\sqrt{-\infty}}{\sqrt{1+\infty}}$ , and I can't see L'Hopitals rule being much use here due to the square root and exponential terms.

Many thanks in advance

Comment: Regardless of $|A|\ne 0$, $\lim_{t\to \infty }N(t)=1\pm i$.

Answer (score 2):

As $t\to\infty$, $Ae^{2rt}\to-\infty$ since $A<0$ and $r$ are fixed. Let $x=Ae^{2rt}$. Then $$N=1\pm\sqrt\frac x{1-x}=1\pm\sqrt\frac1{\frac1x-1}\to1\pm\sqrt\frac1{0-1}$$ as $x\to\infty$ so $$N=1+i, 1-i.$$

Comment: Where did the square root end?

Comment: @ArtificialIntelligence edited thanks

Comment: Since.$A<0$, $\lim_{t\to\infty }Ae^{2rt}=-\infty$.

Answer (score 2):

After some easy algebra, provided that $(A, r) \in\mathbb{R}$, you can rewrite the expression as

$$N = 1  \pm \sqrt{\frac{1}{A\ e^{-2rt} - 1}}$$

And you can easily see that as $t\to \infty$ the denominator is $-1$ hence the whole expression is a complex number:

$$N = 1\pm i$$